# ASP.NET Core with Blazor: Cannot figure out cookie authentification

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, razor-components

I tried to follow this tutorial (http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4316/A-Demonstration-of-Simple-Server-side-Blazor-Cookie-Authentication.aspx) to be able to make an app with cookie authentification with ASP.NET Core 3.0 and Blazor framework v.0.9.0 (the latest version). For IDE I am using VS 2019 Preview.

Author uses earlier version of Blazor, but I followed the tutorial using Client project instead of App, since they do the same thing, I think, just called differently in different version of Blazor.

Here is a link to repo with my result: https://github.com/SaintMSent/TestBlazorCookieAuth

The problem is, it does not work. If I go to localhost:port/login page, cookie is created (I checked Chrome dev tools). And if I go to logout page, it is removed, so this part is fine. But other pages of the app won't load. If I remove Login component from MainLayout, everything is loading fine, so I think the problem is with HttpContext and HttpContextAccessor in Login.cshtml

[image]

Here is what Login.cshtml looks like

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@page "/login"
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor
@inject HttpClient Http
@if (User.Identity.Name != null)
{
    <b>You are logged in as: @User.Identity.Name</b> 
    <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary" 
       href="/logout?returnUrl=/" 
       target="_top">Logout</a>
}
else
{
    <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary" 
       href="/login?returnUrl=/" 
       target="_top">Login</a>
}
@functions {
    private ClaimsPrincipal User;
    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        base.OnInit();
        try
        {
    // Set the user to determine if they are logged in
            User = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Please, help me to figure out what is going on here. I hope I have provided enough details, thanks.

UPDATE: If I add this line

```
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

to Startup.cs in Client project, everything is loading, but _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User is always null

Comment: "using Client project instead of App" - cookies are a server thing (the Browser just holds them). This approach will only work for server-side Blazor.

Comment: "IHttpContextAccessor can be used to access the HttpContext for the current thread". I'm not sure you can use it that way. Use JWT for authentication.

Comment: @if (User.Identity.Name != null){} This is bad... You've got to check if the user is authenticated or not.

Comment: if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
       -------
    }
    else
    {
      -------
    }

Comment: @HenkHolterman in the tutorial author has login and logout pages in server project, but accesses HttpContextAccessor in client project and it works fine, I downloaded his sample, it really works

Comment: @Issac the problem is not with if statement. I looked at the dev tools and there it is said that there is not value of type IHttpContextAccessor for dependency injection. Correctness of the if statement is not what bothers me right now and not the reason I created this thread

Comment: But that client project is also running server-side...  In the newer Blazor updates this would be a Razor Components project. There is no HttpContext in the Browser.

Comment: @HenkHolterman what is your suggestion for my situation?

Comment: You could turn it into a razor-components app (server-side) or stay on the client-side and use JWT or similar.

Comment: @HenkHolterman can I have an example of using JWT on client side in blazor?

Comment: Not here - search for it first and then ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it the strange way. I created a controller I named AuthController and added these methods to it

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getlogin")]
        public string GetLogin()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return $"{User.Identity.Name}";
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getrole")]
        public string GetRole()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    return "Admin";
                }

                return "User";
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

And then I call the API from the client side and it works perfectly for me